# tokenOfOwnerByIndex gives an error "Internal JSON-RPC error."

Tags: error-handling, ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin

I am trying to get the NFT token id holding by the wallet address and code is compiled and deployed successfully but while calling the walletOfOwner function gives me the error below

call to TestNFT.walletOfOwner errored: Internal JSON-RPC error.

{

"code": -32000,

"message": "execution reverted"

}

I am struggling with this error can one anyone please help.

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
 pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Enumerable.sol";
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
 import "./Base64.sol";


  contract TestNFT is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
//using Strings for uint256;
event Minted(uint256 tokenId);
using Counters for Counters.Counter;

Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

string v;
uint256 a;
uint256 b;
uint256 c;
uint256 d;
uint256 e;
uint256 f;
uint256 g;

constructor() ERC721("PTestNFT", "PTN") {}

function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
    if (_i == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    uint j = _i;
    uint len;
    while (j != 0) {
        len++;
        j /= 10;
    }
    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
    uint k = len;
    while (_i != 0) {
        k = k-1;
        uint8 temp = (48 + uint8(_i - _i / 10 * 10));
        bytes1 b1 = bytes1(temp);
        bstr[k] = b1;
        _i /= 10;
    }
    return string(bstr);
}

function svgToImageURI(string memory svg)
    public
    pure
    returns (string memory)
{
    //string memory baseURL = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,";
    string memory baseURL = "ipfs://";
    //string memory svgBase64Encoded = Base64.encode(bytes(svg));
    string memory svgBase64Encoded = svg;
    /* 
    abi.encodePacked is a function provided by Solidity which
    is used to concatenate two strings, similar to a `concat()`
    function in JavaScript.
    */
    return string(abi.encodePacked(baseURL, svgBase64Encoded));
}


function simplifiedFormatTokenURI(string memory imageURI, string memory _v, uint256 _a, uint256 _b, uint256 _c, uint256 _d, uint256 _e, uint256 _f, uint256 _g)
public
pure  
returns (string memory)
{
    string memory baseURL = "data:application/json;base64,";
    string memory json = string(
        abi.encodePacked(
            '{"name": "', 
            _v,'", "description": "A simple SVG based on-chain NFT", "image":"', 
              imageURI, 
            '", "attributes": [ { "trait_type": "A", "value": "', uint2str(_a),'" },  { "trait_type": "B", "value": "', uint2str(_b),'" },  { "trait_type": "C", "value": "', uint2str(_c),'" },  { "trait_type": "D", "value": "', uint2str(_d),'" },  { "trait_type": "E", "value": "', uint2str(_e),'" }, { "trait_type": "F", "value": "', uint2str(_f),'" },  { "trait_type": "G", "value": "', uint2str(_g),'" } ]}'
        )
    );
    string memory jsonBase64Encoded = Base64.encode(bytes(json));
    return string(abi.encodePacked(baseURL, jsonBase64Encoded));
}


function mint(string memory svg, string memory _v, uint256 _a, uint256 _b, uint256 _c, uint256 _d, uint256 _e, uint256 _f, uint256 _g) public {
/* Encode the SVG to a Base64 string and then generate the tokenURI */
    string memory imageURI = svgToImageURI(svg);
    string memory tokenURI = simplifiedFormatTokenURI(imageURI, _v, _a, _b, _c, _d, _e, _f, _g);

    /* Increment the token id everytime we call the mint function */
    _tokenIds.increment();
    
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

    /* Mint the token id and set the token URI */
    _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

    /* Emit an event that returns the newly minted token id */
    emit Minted(newItemId);
}
 function walletOfOwner(address contractAddress, address owner_) public view returns (uint256[] memory){

uint256 _tokenCount = IERC721Enumerable(contractAddress).balanceOf(owner_);
uint256[] memory _tokens = new uint256[](_tokenCount);
for(uint256 i=0; i < _tokenCount; i++){
    _tokens[i] = (IERC721Enumerable(contractAddress).tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner_, i));
}
   return _tokens;
    }


  }
```

Comment: Please share steps to reproduce the issue: 1) On which network are you deploying the `TestNFT` contract? 2) What is the value of `contractAddress` that you're passing to the `walletOfOwner()` function? Is the contract deployed on the same network? Also, if it's not verified on a public network, please share its source code as well.

Comment: @peter Thanks for your reply. 1) TestNFT contract is deployed on Polygon Testnet. 2) The value of **contractAddress** I am passing to **walletofOwner** function is  **0xb13c907750568AB997284994C0EB09A993E0A5c4**. and Yes the contract is deployed on the same network. Also the code is on the github [link](https://github.com/pks2412/testnft/blob/main/TestNFT.sol)